# VBA dynamic row lookup while looping

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I'm very new to VBA and should probably spend some time on debugging and learning the formalities of how code should be written.

I am using a loop that uses the Hlookup function to populate a table from on one sheet from data on a master sheet. (This is in the Sub SetMatrix).  Within the Sub that performs this task I use some other UDF's, one which copies and pastes the variables (names from a 3rd sheet which may change) I want to lookup from the master sheet.

In any case it runs perfectly fine when the I use a hardcoded number for the row in the lookup function. However, once I try to use a variable (jpmRow instead of a number like 50) for the row it will work the first time only. Then when I run it again I get RunTime error 91 - object variable or withblock variable not set. The debugger take me back to the DynamicRange UDF, Set StartCell line, which confuses me because that is not where I am setting the row variable. Meanwhile if I use a constant for the row it lets me rerun the sub with success every time.

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim TxtCell As Range
Dim PortfolioCell As String
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim EndCell As Range
Dim RangeParameter As Range
Dim jpmRow As Integer
Dim myColumn As Integer
Dim myRow As Integer



Function DynamicRange(TxtToFind As String) As Range


Dim k As Integer

k = iCount

Set ws = Sheets("Template")

Set StartCell = ws.Cells.Find(TxtToFind).Offset(2, 0)
myColumn = StartCell.Column
myRow = StartCell.Row
Set EndCell = ws.Cells(myRow + k - 1, myColumn)

Set DynamicRange = ws.Range(StartCell.Address, EndCell.Address)

'Set DynamicRange = RangeParameter

End Function
Function iCount() As Integer



Set ws = Sheets("Template")

Set StartCell = ws.Cells.Find("Ticker").Offset(2, 0)
Set EndCell = ws.Cells.Find("Total").Offset(-1, 0)

iCount = ws.Range(StartCell.Address, EndCell.Address).Rows.Count


End Function



Sub SetMatrix()

Dim StartTable As Range
Dim iRows As Range
Dim iColumns As Range
Dim myArray(50, 50) As Integer

Dim wsJPM As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer


Set StartTable = Sheets("Correlation Matrix").Range("A3")
Set iRows = Range(StartTable.Offset(1, 0).Address, StartTable.Offset(iCount, 0).Address)
Set iColumns = Range(StartTable.Offset(0, 1).Address, StartTable.Offset(0, iCount).Address)
Set wsJPM = Sheets("JPM")

Sheets("Correlation Matrix").Cells.ClearContents
Sheets("Correlation Matrix").Cells.ClearFormats

DynamicRange("Asset Class").Copy iRows
DynamicRange("Asset Class").Copy
iColumns.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True


For i = 1 To iCount

    For j = 1 To iCount
    jpmRow = wsJPM.Cells.Find(StartTable.Offset(i, 0), SearchOrder:=xlColumns, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
    StartTable.Offset(i, j).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.HLookup(StartTable.Offset(0, j), Sheets("JPM").Range("B1:BZ100"), jpmRow, False)
    Next j

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: The most likely issue is that the search term is not being found. You cannot Offset from a non-existent range. Step through your code to see what's going on.

Comment: Have a read of [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel).  Take note of the line `If Not c Is Nothing Then` where it checks if it found anything.